# Missing directive or assembly reference for SoapException

Tags: salesforce

I'm using the salesforce API and have a helper class that returns a SaveResult array.  I'm using a try/catch block and I'm using SoapException in my catch block, but the namespace is not found.  I'm not sure what using directive I should use?

The examples in the API guide show SoapException as a valid type.

Here is my method:

```
    private SaveResult[] CreateObjects(sObject[] objectArray)
    {
        try
        {
            SaveResult[] saveResults = this.binding.create(objectArray);

            for (int i = 0; i < saveResults.Length; i++)
            {
                if (saveResults[i].success)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("An object was created with Id: {0}", saveResults[i].id);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Item {0} had an error updating", i);

                    foreach (Error error in saveResults[i].errors)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error code is: {0}",
                        error.statusCode.ToString());
                        Console.WriteLine("Error message: {0}", error.message);
                    }
                }
            }
            return saveResults;
        }
        catch (SoapException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Code);
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its the library provided SoapException class, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapexception.aspx